# If one of the triangles AIB,BIC, or CIA is similar to triangle ABC,if x is the smallest angle of ABC then which of the following is true?

Tags: trigonometry

Let I denote the centre of the inscribed circle in triangle ABC.If one of the triangles AIB,BIC, or CIA is similar to triangle ABC,if x is the smallest angle of ABC then which of the following is true?

(A) $\tan(x)\tan(2x)\tan(3x)=\tan(3x)-\tan(2x)-\tan(x) $

(B) $ \ cosec (x)= \ cosec(2x)+\ cosec(4x)$

(C) $\cos(x)-\cos(2x)+\cos(3x)$ has the value $1/2$

(D)$8\cos(x)\cos(2x)\cos(4x)$ has the value $1$.

Ok I think I can so the proofs by myself once I understand the diagram.But Suppose I take triangle BIA is similar to ABC then how should I take the angles of BIA ? I'm confused with that.Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong in the question since if you suppose $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle AIB  $, Then $\angle BAC = \angle IAB$ but since I is the incentre, it must be the point of intersection of the bisectors of the angles of the triangle. which means that $\angle IAB = {\angle BAC\over 2} = \angle BAC \Rightarrow \angle BAC = 0$ which is obviously not possible. Even if you consider the other cases, you'll get a similar unacceptable result. Thus in order to get an answer to the question, you'll have to consider the other four permutations of $AIB$, i.e. $IAB, IBA, BAI, BIA$

Thus consider for example $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle IAB$ [image]

See here that $$\angle IAB = {\angle BAC\over 2} = \angle ABC$$ $$\angle ABI = {\angle ABC\over 2} = \angle ACB$$
Thus we have the following relation $$\angle BAC = 2 \angle ABC = 4\angle ACB \ \mathbb{or} \ \angle A = 2\angle B = 4\angle C$$ Thus you'll get $x = {\pi\over 7}$
and the problem may be simple for you from this step onwards. I suppose that for all other allowed permutations, you'll get a similar result.

Comment: You can possibly have $\angle BAC=\angle IBA$ or $\angle BAC=\angle AIB$. These don't lead to impossibilities.

Comment: No I $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle AIB \Rightarrow \angle ABC = \angle AIB, \angle BAC = \angle IAB \ \mathbb{ and } \ \angle ACB = \angle ABI $, you've to consider the order of the vertices when you're looking for similarility.

Comment: Very often saying that two triangles are similar means that the angles are equal in some order, not necessarily in the order specified by writing out the triangles' vertices. I suspect this is the case in this question.